# I can not install ipython3-notebook in 12.04.5 amd64

Tags: 12.04, ipython

When installing it , ubuntu gives the below message :

```
ipython3-notebook:
  Depends: ipython3 (=0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.2) but 0.12.1+dfsg-0ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
```

How to do with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

so issuing:

```
 sudo apt-get install ipython3-notebook -t precise-backports
```

just now  fixed it on my system (12.04 LTS).

( meaning "ipython3 notebook --pylab inline &" launches without issue)

from:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ipython/+bug/1361944

> "...ipython3-notebook is in the backports repository, apt is not smart enough to figure out it needs to pull more from it, specifically it needs ipython-notebook-common. ..."